# twitter script not want to load value of variable from theme options

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I use this script for twitter for my theme http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/custom-twitter-feed-integration-jquery/ .. but now I have some problem.. I add option to user can write username in Theme option.. and I call it like this "get_option('swt_twitter_link')" but from some reason when I try to add this to get-tweets1.1.php file the script not want to work.. its look like value is not added for username from theme options.. This is how file code look like...

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library

$twitteruser = sweden;
$notweets = 30;
$consumerkey = "consumerkey";
$consumersecret = "consumersecret";
$accesstoken = "accesstoken";
$accesstokensecret = "accesstokensecret";

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

echo json_encode($tweets);
?>
```

Comment: Does $twitteruser value should be without quotes ?

Comment: actually its work with and without quotes, if I put just sweden but if I put get_option('swt_twitter_link') ... its not want to work.. I forget to tell that this get-tweets1.1.php file called by script twitterfeed.js ..... with this part of code ....   $.getJSON(templateUrl + '/includes/twitteroauth/get-tweets1.1.php',

Comment: Does var_dump(get_option('swt_twitter_link')); returns correct value ?

Comment: I did not use this var_dump(get_option('swt_twitter_link')); .. to call username is in php get-tweets1.1.php and then in twitterfeed.js is call for this get-tweets1.1.php .. but in js file is no var_dump(get_option('swt_twitter_link'));

Comment: I try to add this but nothing :(  .... $twitteruser = var_dump(get_option('swt_twitter_link'));

Comment: var_dump() - is not a solution for your problem. I just want to know what data returned from get_option('swt_twitter_link')

Comment: when I add this var_dump(get_option('swt_twitter_link')); ... and for twitter_link in Theme options I write sweden... I get this like result .... string(6) "sweden"

Comment: behaves as if nothing is in get_option('swt_twitter_link') .. but with var_dump(get_option('swt_twitter_link')); I get ... string(6) "sweden" .. I get value I write in Theme options.. Why is not want to add it on 

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

echo json_encode($tweets);

Comment: anybody please :( @ValeryStatichny

Comment: I add wp-load.php and still nothing.. I do not understund why is this not want to work!!!!